How to resolve the issue with the @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react module lacking TypeScript definitions
How to resolve the issue with the @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react module lacking TypeScript definitions.
Could not find a declaration file for module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'. 'c:/develop/eachblock/aquatrack/management-tool-app/node_modules/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react/dist/tawk-messenger-react.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm i --save-dev @types/tawk.to__tawk-messenger-reactif it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containingdeclare module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react';``
After installing the tawk using
npm i @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react
I then create a new component in the component folder named TawkMessenger, and add this to the component:
`import TawkMessengerReact from "@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react";
const TawkMessenger = () => {
  return (
      <TawkMessengerReact
        propertyId="YOUR_PROPERTY_ID"
        widgetId="YOUR_WIDGET_ID"
      />
  ); 
};
export default TawkMessenger;`

But I keep getting this error
Could not find a declaration file for module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'. 'c:/develop/eachblock/aquatrack/management-tool-app/node_modules/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react/dist/tawk-messenger-react.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm i --save-dev @types/tawk.to__tawk-messenger-reactif it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containingdeclare module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react';``
But when I follow the instructions and try to install the  npm i --save-dev @types/tawk.to__tawk-messenger-react It was unable to install.

I finally resolved the issue and this is how I did it.
Create a new file named tawk-messenger-react.d.ts in your project's src directory (or another appropriate location).
Inside tawk-messenger-react.d.ts, declare the module and provide basic typings. This will inform TypeScript about the existence of the module and its general shape.
declare module '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react' {
  import React from 'react';

  interface TawkMessengerProps {
    propertyId: string;
    widgetId: string;
  }

  const TawkMessenger: React.FC<TawkMessengerProps>;

  export default TawkMessenger;
}

This works for me!!
